# How to ensure data locality in Spark data source v2?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datasource

I implement Spark data source (v2) and I didn't find a way to ensure data locality.

In data source v1 `getPreferredLocations` method can be implemented, what is the equivalent in data source v2?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark data source v2 you should change to [SupportsReportPartitioning](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.2/sql/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/SupportsReportPartitioning.java)

I see someone discuss some limitation in this issue [SPARK-15689 - Data source API v2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689)

> So **SupportsReportPartitioning** is not powerful enough to support custom hash functions yet. There are two major operators that may introduce shuffle: join and aggregate. Aggregate only needs to have the data clustered, but doesn't care how, so the data source v2 can support it, if your implementation catches ClusteredDistribution. Join needs the data of the 2 children clustered by the spark shuffle hash function, which is not supported by data source v2 currently.